# Using htmlpurifier with annotations in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8, htmlpurifier

I would like to use the htmlpurifier not as a form data transformer, but rather as an annotation in the entities property.

The problem: In the Symfony 2.8 project we use a lot of different types of forms, some using symfonies formbuilder, some via sonata-admin, some using twig and ajax etc ..

So using a transformer and a custom field type is not the way to go.
Also, editing every single create or update action would be overkill.

I've been playing with the idea of an event listener on prePersist, but with such a large amount of different entities in our project we would most likely incur a performance hit if this were to be called on every persist() action. Limiting it to only specific object types would also be painstaking.

Is it possible to use the htmlpurifier bundle as an annotation only on the properties that matter?

eg:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="uprename", length=20, nullable=true)
 * @htmlpurifier('default')
 */
private $firstName;
```

Where `default` would be the default configuration.

bundle: https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find an answer? I am facing the same issue now..